# VS Code no longer recognizing CLI Extensions

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

In the past week, VS Code no longer recognizes the CLI/SFDX.

I have verified that I can create projects with sfdx force:project:create and the correct folder structure is created.

However, when leveraging the command pallette it returns that it cannot find the command.

Additionally, if I create the project manually through sfdx/cli, even though there's a sfdx-project.json, no other commands such as 'Authorize' appear in the pallette.

I have uninstalled SFDX, uninstalled VS Code, purged all directories, ran MacOS updates, and restarted. All to no avail.

Has anyone ran across this before?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a current known issue: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/3901

Comment: Thanks, found that right before coming here and was going to update. Rolling back the extension and restarting VS Code did resolve it.